# downgrade asp.net 4.5 to 4.0 plesk 11.5 windows

Tags: windows, asp.net-4.0, plesk, asp.net-4.5

How to downgraded from `ASP.NET 4.5` to `ASP.NET 4.0` on the windows `plesk 11.5`?

I've tried to search that function in the Add and Remove Product Components on the `plesk` control panel.

There is only `ASP.NET 4.0` in the Server `Components-> Web scripting`.

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.parallels.com/en/115337
Note #1: as .NET 4.5 Framework is iterative update to .NET 4.0, Parallels Plesk Panel and IIS will continue displaying available version of ASP.NET as 4.0.